# Prettily dump 2D array to YAML in Python

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Suppose I have a 2D array defined like so:

```
import sys

from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
yaml.version = (1,2)

def main():
    data = {
        "foo": [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6]
        ]
    }
    yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like to output a "readable", valid YAML file with each "row" on a separate line:

```
"foo":
- [1,2,3]
- [4,5,6]
```

or even

```
"foo": [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,5]
]
```

I've looked into `ruamel.yaml` but the default behavior is each column on a separate line which, while valid, is not easily readable:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
foo:
- - 1
  - 2
  - 3
- - 4
  - 5
  - 6
```

Comment: do you have to use your library or can you just use default python libraries? This would be pretty easy with just default py.

Comment: @javanix Are your 2D arrays really objects or are they just list of lists? If they are objects, you should dump them with an appropriate tag (and then you can let the representer take care of properly formatting)

Comment: @d_kennetz What do you mean by default libraries? There is no YAML loader/dumper in the standard python library, nor is there a `default.py` in the standard library. It is of course trivial to write out a file with the content the OP wants, but to make an arbitrary deep data tree come out correctly as YAML is non-trivial.

Comment: It's actually a list of stdlib strings/ints just as described above. I need ruamel.yaml for the comment support - that's not really relevant to the question at hand here though so I omitted it.

@Anthon this is just build system configuration - it's not objects, just an 2d array of strings/ints that I want to pretty-print - .default_flow_style does the trick - thanks for the help.

Comment: @Anthon he says dump 2D array, not deep data tree. default libraries would be any standard python library (I don't think this is confusing). Anyway, your answer seems to cover what he wants perfectly! To clarify, I see the ambiguity in the part "default py" as being interpreted as default.py. Sorry for any confusion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set the attribute `.default_flow_style` to `None` (instead of the default value `False`), 
your leaf-nodes will be represented in flow style:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.version = (1,2)
yaml.default_flow_style = None

def main():
    data = {
        "foo": [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6]
        ]
    }
    yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which gives:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
foo:
- [1, 2, 3]
- [4, 5, 6]
```

But the above works for the whole file.

If you want an individual lists to be represented as flow-style sequences in YAML, you
should make them of the type `CommentedSeq` and then you can set the attribute **per object**.
That is also the way `ruamel.yaml` "knows" how to preserve the style of a sequence when round-tripping:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.version = (1,2)

a = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq([1,2,3])
a.fa.set_flow_style()


def main():
    data = {
        "foo": [
        a,
            [4,5,6]
        ]
    }
    yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

giving:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
foo:
- [1, 2, 3]
- - 4
  - 5
  - 6
```